# c# from windows service to desktop application

Tags: c#

can someone tell me and also give me a short example of how could i make a bridge from a windows service to a c# console application (form application) project? i would need a short example. What should i write in the start, continue and stop methods that windows service has?

EDIT

I have a c# project. i just want to run it from a windows service using a brige..or somthing. i know communication between sessions is not possible

Comment: If you can give a short example of what you are trying to achieve, you are more likely to get good answers.

Comment: It's unclear if your trying to write a second app to talk to the service app, or if you want to re write your service to run as a standard app.

Answer (score 2):

The bridge you speak of is normally called IPC ( inter process communication) and can be done in n + 1 ways.  The one I would suggest you look at is WCF since it is a framework that allows you many ways to do IPC. Hear is a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx).